# What's the fastest way to do a bulk insert into Postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I need to programmatically insert tens of millions of records into a Postgres database. Presently, I'm executing thousands of insert statements in a single query.

Is there a better way to do this, some bulk insert statement I do not know about?

Answer (score 304, accepted):

PostgreSQL has [a guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html) on how to best populate a database initially, and they suggest using the [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) command for bulk loading rows.  The guide has some other good tips on how to speed up the process, like removing indexes and foreign keys before loading the data (and adding them back afterwards).

Comment: I wrote a bit more detail to elaborate in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206600/how-to-speed-up-insertion-performance-in-postgresql too.

Comment: @CraigRinger Wow, "a bit more detail" is the best understatement I have seen all week ;)

Comment: Try Install-Package NpgsqlBulkCopy

Comment: -Since indexes are also used for physical layout of the db records. Not sure if removing indexes in any database is a good idea.

Comment: But your recommended , nothing in Memory!!! And if your batch size can be small number , very-very bad worked it's class  :( I Try npgsql CopyIn class, because it's like as CSV formatted mapping in    PG query statement's. You can try for Big Table?

Answer (score 171):

There is an alternative to using COPY, which is the multirow values syntax that Postgres supports. From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-insert.html):

```
INSERT INTO films (code, title, did, date_prod, kind) VALUES
    ('B6717', 'Tampopo', 110, '1985-02-10', 'Comedy'),
    ('HG120', 'The Dinner Game', 140, DEFAULT, 'Comedy');
```

The above code inserts two rows, but you can extend it arbitrarily, until you hit the maximum number of prepared statement tokens (it might be $999, but I'm not 100% sure about that). Sometimes one cannot use COPY, and this is a worthy replacement for those situations.

Comment: Do you know how the performance of this method compares to COPY?

Comment: If you run into a permissions problem, before trying this, use COPY ... FROM STDIN

Comment: If you're using row-level security, this is the best you can do. "COPY FROM is not supported for tables with row-level security" as of version 12.

Comment: COPY is a lot faster than extended INSERT

Comment: Most important in this kind of procedure (raw data **ingestion**) is the transformation, **expressed in a SQL standard** (no use of exotic tools). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62493516/287948

Comment: The performance here for me was perfect. 370K rows in 3.291 seconds.

Comment: Due to the PostgreSQL wire protocol a maximum number of parameters are limited to 2 bytes (short C type) that limits it to 65535 data binding parameters.

Answer (score 30):

One way to speed things up is to explicitly perform multiple inserts or copy's within a transaction (say 1000). Postgres's default behavior is to commit after each statement, so by batching the commits, you can avoid some overhead. As the guide in Daniel's answer says, you may have to disable autocommit for this to work. Also note the comment at the bottom that suggests increasing the size of the wal_buffers to 16 MB may also help.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the limit for how many inserts/copies you can add to the same transaction is likely much higher than anything you'll attempt. You could add millions and millions of rows within the same transaction and not run into problems.

Comment: @SumeetJain Yes, I'm just remarking on the speed 'sweet spot' in terms of the number of copies/inserts per transaction.

Comment: Will this lock the table while the transaction is running?

Answer (score 23):

[`UNNEST`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-array.html) function with arrays can be used along with multirow VALUES syntax. I'm think that this method is slower than using `COPY` but it is useful to me in work with psycopg and python (python `list` passed to `cursor.execute` becomes pg `ARRAY`):

```
INSERT INTO tablename (fieldname1, fieldname2, fieldname3)
VALUES (
    UNNEST(ARRAY[1, 2, 3]), 
    UNNEST(ARRAY[100, 200, 300]), 
    UNNEST(ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c'])
);
```

without `VALUES` using subselect with additional existance check:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (fieldname1, fieldname2, fieldname3)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1, 2, 3]), 
           UNNEST(ARRAY[100, 200, 300]), 
           UNNEST(ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c'])
) AS temptable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM tablename tt
    WHERE tt.fieldname1=temptable.fieldname1
);
```

the same syntax to bulk updates:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET fieldname1=temptable.data
FROM (
    SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1,2]) AS id,
           UNNEST(ARRAY['a', 'b']) AS data
) AS temptable
WHERE tablename.id=temptable.id;
```

Answer (score 19):

((this is a WIKI you can edit and enhance the answer!))

### The external file is the best and typical bulk-data

The term "bulk data"  is related to "a lot of data", so it is natural to use **original raw data**, with no need to transform it into SQL. Typical raw  data files for "bulk insert" are [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and [JSON](https://www.json.org) formats.

### Bulk insert with some transformation

In [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) applications  and ingestion processes, we need to change the data before inserting it. Temporary table consumes (a lot of) disk space, and it is not the faster way to do it. The [PostgreSQL foreign-data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/postgres-fdw.html) (FDW) is the best choice.

**CSV example**. Suppose the `tablename (x, y, z)` on SQL and a CSV file like

```
fieldname1,fieldname2,fieldname3
etc,etc,etc
... million lines ...
```

You can use the classic SQL `COPY` to load (*as is* original data) into `tmp_tablename`, them insert filtered data into `tablename`... But, to avoid disk consumption, the best is to ingested directly by

```sql
INSERT INTO tablename (x, y, z)
  SELECT f1(fieldname1), f2(fieldname2), f3(fieldname3) -- the transforms 
  FROM tmp_tablename_fdw
  -- WHERE condictions
;
```

You need to prepare database for FDW, and instead static `tmp_tablename_fdw` you can use [a function that generates it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12780275/287948):

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION file_fdw;
CREATE SERVER import FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw;
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE tmp_tablename_fdw(
  ...
) SERVER import OPTIONS ( filename '/tmp/pg_io/file.csv', format 'csv');
```

**JSON example**. A set of two files, `myRawData1.json` and `Ranger_Policies2.json` can be ingested by:

```sql
INSERT INTO tablename (fname, metadata, content)
 SELECT fname, meta, j  -- do any data transformation here
 FROM jsonb_read_files('myRawData%.json')
 -- WHERE any_condiction_here
;
```

where the function *jsonb_read_files()* reads all files of a folder, defined by a mask:

```sql
CREATE or replace FUNCTION jsonb_read_files(
  p_flike text, p_fpath text DEFAULT '/tmp/pg_io/'
) RETURNS TABLE (fid int, fname text, fmeta jsonb, j jsonb) AS $f$
  WITH t AS (
     SELECT (row_number() OVER ())::int id, 
           f AS fname,
           p_fpath ||'/'|| f AS f
     FROM pg_ls_dir(p_fpath) t(f)
     WHERE f LIKE p_flike
  ) SELECT id, fname,
         to_jsonb( pg_stat_file(f) ) || jsonb_build_object('fpath', p_fpath),
         pg_read_file(f)::jsonb
    FROM t
$f$  LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

### Lack of gzip streaming

The most frequent method for "file ingestion" (mainlly in Big Data) is preserving original file on  [gzip format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) and transfering it with [streaming algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_algorithm), anything  that can runs fast and without disc consumption in unix pipes:

```
 gunzip remote_or_local_file.csv.gz | convert_to_sql | psql
```

So ideal (future) is a *server option* for format  `.csv.gz`.

Note after @CharlieClark comment: currently (2022) nothing to do, the best alternative seems [`pgloader` STDIN](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#reading-from-stdin):

```
  gunzip -c file.csv.gz | pgloader --type csv ... - pgsql:///target?foo
```

Comment: When I tried using FDW for a very large (> 10 GB) CSV I hit memory problems with Postges (along with handling some of the bizarre mistakes in the MySQL export) and couldn't find any way around this.

Comment: @CharlieClark, PostgreSQL version?  You can report the error, here or [at the PostgreSQL options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/bug-reporting.html). Another solution is to split... test for example Unix `head -n 1000 file.csv > file_test.csv` to check by FDW the first 1000 lines, the problem can be a malformed CSV. PS: to fix a malformed CSV you can use [csvformat](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvformat.html)

Comment: I've had the errors with different versions of Postgres but the most recent was 13. I haven't pursued other options because pgloader covers most of them, but I was surprised at the memory problems.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `COPY table TO ... WITH BINARY` which is "[somewhat faster than the text and CSV formats](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html)." Only do this if you have millions of rows to insert, and if you are comfortable with binary data.

Here is an [example recipe in Python, using psycopg2 with binary input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144002/use-binary-copy-table-from-with-psycopg2/8150329#8150329).

Answer (score 10):

It mostly depends on the (other) activity in the database. Operations like this effectively freeze the entire database for other sessions. Another consideration is the datamodel and the presence of constraints,triggers, etc.

My first approach is always: create a (temp) table with a structure similar to the target table (`create table tmp AS select * from target where 1=0`), and start by reading the file into the temp table.
Then I check what can be checked: duplicates, keys that already exist in the target, etc.

Then I just do a `do insert into target select * from tmp` or similar.

If this fails, or takes too long, I abort it and consider other methods (temporarily dropping indexes/constraints, etc)

Answer (score 5):

I just encountered this issue and would recommend [csvsql](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io) ([releases](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit/releases)) for bulk imports to Postgres. To perform a bulk insert you'd simply `createdb` and then use `csvsql`, which connects to your database and creates individual tables for an entire folder of CSVs.

```
$ createdb test 
$ csvsql --db postgresql:///test --insert examples/*.csv
```

Comment: For csvsql, in order to also clean the source csv from any possible formating errors, it is best to follow [these instructions](http://sptl.eu/2015/01/03/import-csv-data-into-postgresql-the-comfortable-way/), more documentation [here](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.1/scripts/csvsql.html)

Answer (score 2):

May be I'm late already. But, there is a Java library called `pgbulkinsert` by Bytefish. Me and my team were able to bulk insert 1 Million records in 15 seconds. Of course, there were some other operations that we performed like, reading 1M+ records from a file sitting on Minio, do couple of processing on the top of 1M+ records, filter down records if duplicates, and then finally insert 1M records into the Postgres Database. And all these processes were completed within 15 seconds. I don't remember exactly how much time it took to do the DB operation, but I think it was around less then 5 seconds. Find more details from https://www.bytefish.de/blog/pgbulkinsert_bulkprocessor.html

Comment: I was able to insert 1M records in 3.7 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, when importing data into Postgres, things will be slowed by the checks that Postgres is designed to do for you. Also, you often need to manipulate the data in one way or another so that it's suitable for use. Any of this that can be done outside of the Postgres process will mean that you can import using the COPY protocol.

For my use I regularly import data from the [httparchive.org](https://legacy.httparchive.org) project using [pgloader](https://pgloader.io). As the source files are created by MySQL you need to be able to handle some MySQL oddities such as the use of `\N` for an empty value and along with encoding problems. The files are also so large that, at least on my machine, using FDW runs out of memory. pgloader makes it easy to create a pipeline that lets you select the fields you want, cast to the relevant data types and any additional work before it goes into your main database so that index updates, etc. are minimal.

Answer (score -1):

The query below can create **`test` table** with **`generate_series` column** which has **10000 rows**. *I usually create such **`test` table** to test query performance and you can check [**generate_series()**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html):

```sql
CREATE TABLE test AS SELECT generate_series(1, 10000);
```

```
postgres=# SELECT count(*) FROM test;
 count
-------
 10000
(1 row)
```

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM test;
 generate_series
-----------------
               1
               2
               3
               4
               5
               6
-- More --
```

And, run the query below to insert **10000 rows** if you've already had **`test` table**:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (generate_series) SELECT generate_series(1, 10000);
```