# How to improve the speed of this code?

Tags: java, performance, postgresql, dataset, google-books

I'm trying to import all googlebooks-1gram files into a postgresql database. I wrote the following Java code for that:

```
public class ToPostgres {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String filePath = "./";
        List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i =0; i < 10; i++) {
            files.add(filePath+"googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20090715-"+i+".csv");
        }
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/googlebooks",
                    "postgres", "xxxxxx");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (c != null) {
            try {
                PreparedStatement wordInsert = c.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO words (word) VALUES (?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS
                );
                PreparedStatement countInsert = c.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO wordcounts (word_id, \"year\", total_count, total_pages, total_books) " +
                    "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
                );
                String lastWord = "";
                Long lastId = -1L;
                for (String filename: files) {
                    BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] data = line.split("\t");
                        Long id = -1L;
                        if (lastWord.equals(data[0])) {
                            id = lastId;
                        } else {
                            wordInsert.setString(1, data[0]);
                            wordInsert.executeUpdate();
                            ResultSet resultSet = wordInsert.getGeneratedKeys();
                            if (resultSet != null && resultSet.next()) 
                            {
                                id = resultSet.getLong(1);
                            }
                        }
                        countInsert.setLong(1, id);
                        countInsert.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
                        countInsert.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(data[2]));
                        countInsert.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(data[3]));
                        countInsert.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(data[4]));
                        countInsert.executeUpdate();
                        lastWord = data[0];
                        lastId = id;
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

However, when running this for ~3 hours it only placed 1.000.000 entries in the wordcounts table. When I check the amount of lines in the entire 1gram dataset it's 500.000.000 lines. So to import everything would take about 62.5 days, I can accept that it imports in about a week, but 2 months? I think I'm doing something seriously wrong here(I do have a server that runs 24/7, so I can actually run it for this long, but faster would be nice XD)

EDIT: This code is how I solved it:

```
public class ToPostgres {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String filePath = "./";
        List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i =0; i < 10; i++) {
            files.add(filePath+"googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20090715-"+i+".csv");
        }
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/googlebooks",
                    "postgres", "xxxxxx");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (c != null) {
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            try {
                PreparedStatement wordInsert = c.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO words (id, word) VALUES (?,?)"
                );
                PreparedStatement countInsert = c.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO wordcounts (word_id, \"year\", total_count, total_pages, total_books) " +
                    "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
                );
                String lastWord = "";
                Long id = 0L;
                for (String filename: files) {
                    BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));
                    String line = "";
                    int i = 0;
                    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] data = line.split("\t");
                        if (!lastWord.equals(data[0])) {
                            id++;
                            wordInsert.setLong(1, id);
                            wordInsert.setString(2, data[0]);
                            wordInsert.executeUpdate();
                        }
                        countInsert.setLong(1, id);
                        countInsert.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
                        countInsert.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(data[2]));
                        countInsert.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(data[3]));
                        countInsert.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(data[4]));
                        countInsert.executeUpdate();
                        lastWord = data[0];
                        if (i % 10000 == 0) {
                            c.commit();
                        }
                        if (i % 100000 == 0) {
                            System.out.println(i+" mark file "+filename);
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    c.commit();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I reached 1.5 million rows in about 15 minutes now. That's fast enough for me, thanks all!

Comment: Try running without executing the SQL, you'll probably find you need to tweak your PostgreSQL database more than anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JDBC connections have autocommit enabled by default, which carries a per-statement overhead. Try disabling it:

```
c.setAutoCommit(false)
```

then commit in batches, something along the lines of:

```
long ops = 0;

for(String filename : files) {
    // ...
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        // insert some stuff...

        ops ++;

        if(ops % 1000 == 0) {
            c.commit();
        }
    }
}

c.commit();
```

Comment: I'll try that, in combination with all of the other improvements suggested here this could surely help :)

Answer (score 3):

If your table has indexes, it might be faster to delete them, insert the data, and recreate the indexes later.

Setting autocommit off, and doing a manual commit every 10 000 records or so (look into the documentation for a reasonable value - there is some limit) could speed up as well.

Generating the index/foreign key yourself, and keeping track of it should be faster than `wordInsert.getGeneratedKeys();` but I'm not sure, whether it is possible from your content.

There is an approach called 'bulk insert'. I don't remember the details, but its a starting point for a search.

Comment: Nice tip about the keys, I could easily generate those myself

Comment: Yes, and you can create an autoincrement later with a given seed.

Comment: Bulk insert in postgres from a file is done with the [`COPY` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-copy.html)

Answer (score 2):

Write it to do threading, running 4 threads at the same time, or split it up in sections (read from config file) and distribute it to X machines and have them get the data togeather.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose threading could help, unfortunately I only got 1 machine I can run it on, and that has only 2 cores. So the max speed it could have would still be 31.25 days

Comment: I'm not sure this math is correct, as while reading files, or updating database the cores are sitting idle, so having 5-6-7 threads will probably still show improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Use [batch statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29) to execute multiple inserts at the same time, rather than one INSERT at a time.

In addition I would remove the part of your algorithm which updates the word count after each insert into the `words` table, instead just calculate all of the word counts once inserting the `words` is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to do bulk inserts rather than single inserts. See this question [Whats the fastest way to do a bulk insert into Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758945/whats-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-bulk-insert-into-postgres) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Create threads

```
String lastWord = "";
    Long lastId = -1L;
    PreparedStatement wordInsert;
    PreparedStatement countInsert ;
    public class ToPostgres {
        public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String filePath = "./";
            List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i =0; i < 10; i++) {
                files.add(filePath+"googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20090715-"+i+".csv");
            }
            Connection c = null;
            try {
                c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/googlebooks",
                        "postgres", "xxxxxx");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (c != null) {
                try {
                    wordInsert = c.prepareStatement(
                        "INSERT INTO words (word) VALUES (?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS
                    );
                    countInsert = c.prepareStatement(
                        "INSERT INTO wordcounts (word_id, \"year\", total_count, total_pages, total_books) " +
                        "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
                    );
                    for (String filename: files) {
                        new MyThread(filename). start();
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
    class MyThread extends Thread{
        String file;
        public MyThread(String file) {
            this.file = file;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {         
            try {
                super.run();
                BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(file)));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] data = line.split("\t");
                    Long id = -1L;
                    if (lastWord.equals(data[0])) {
                        id = lastId;
                    } else {
                        wordInsert.setString(1, data[0]);
                        wordInsert.executeUpdate();
                        ResultSet resultSet = wordInsert.getGeneratedKeys();
                        if (resultSet != null && resultSet.next()) 
                        {
                            id = resultSet.getLong(1);
                        }
                    }
                    countInsert.setLong(1, id);
                    countInsert.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
                    countInsert.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(data[2]));
                    countInsert.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(data[3]));
                    countInsert.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(data[4]));
                    countInsert.executeUpdate();
                    lastWord = data[0];
                    lastId = id;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```