# Use binary COPY table FROM with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, bulkinsert, binary-data, psycopg2

I have tens of millions of rows to transfer from multidimensional array files into a PostgreSQL database. My tools are Python and psycopg2. The most efficient way to bulk instert data is using [`copy_from`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from). However, my data are mostly 32-bit floating point numbers (real or float4), so I'd rather not convert from real → text → real. Here is an example database DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE num_data
(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  node integer NOT NULL,
  ts smallint NOT NULL,
  val1 real,
  val2 double precision
);
```

Here is where I'm at with Python using strings (text):

```py
# Just one row of data
num_row = [23253, 342, -15.336734, 2494627.949375]

import psycopg2
# Python3:
from io import StringIO
# Python2, use: from cStringIO import StringIO

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mydb user=postgres")
curs = conn.cursor()

# Convert floating point numbers to text, write to COPY input
cpy = StringIO()
cpy.write('\t'.join([repr(x) for x in num_row]) + '\n')

# Insert data; database converts text back to floating point numbers
cpy.seek(0)
curs.copy_from(cpy, 'num_data', columns=('node', 'ts', 'val1', 'val2'))
conn.commit()
```

Is there an equivalent that could work using a binary mode? I.e., keep the floating point numbers in binary? Not only would this preserve the floating point precision, but it could be faster.

(Note: to see the same precision as the example, use `SET extra_float_digits='2'`)

Comment: Well, you can [import binary files with COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-copy.html), but for that the whole file has to be in a specific binary format, not just the one value.

Comment: @Erwin, yes I read about the binary mode for COPY, but I'm just not sure if it is supported by psycopg2, or if I should use a different approach.

Comment: The only application of the binary file format I have used is to import a file that was exported *from* PostgreSQL. I don't know of any other program that can write the specific format. Doesn't mean it couldn't be out there somewhere, though. If it is for a repeated operation, you might COPY to Postgres in text form once, write the binary file out and `COPY FROM .. FORMAT BINARY` next time.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here is the binary equivalent of COPY FROM for Python 3:

```py
from io import BytesIO
from struct import pack
import psycopg2

# Two rows of data; "id" is not in the upstream data source
# Columns: node, ts, val1, val2
data = [(23253, 342, -15.336734, 2494627.949375),
        (23256, 348, 43.23524, 2494827.949375)]

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mydb user=postgres")
curs = conn.cursor()

# Determine starting value for sequence
curs.execute("SELECT nextval('num_data_id_seq')")
id_seq = curs.fetchone()[0]

# Make a binary file object for COPY FROM
cpy = BytesIO()
# 11-byte signature, no flags, no header extension
cpy.write(pack('!11sii', b'PGCOPY\n\377\r\n\0', 0, 0))

# Columns: id, node, ts, val1, val2
# Zip: (column position, format, size)
row_format = list(zip(range(-1, 4),
                      ('i', 'i', 'h', 'f', 'd'),
                      ( 4,   4,   2,   4,   8 )))
for row in data:
    # Number of columns/fields (always 5)
    cpy.write(pack('!h', 5))
    for col, fmt, size in row_format:
        value = (id_seq if col == -1 else row[col])
        cpy.write(pack('!i' + fmt, size, value))
    id_seq += 1  # manually increment sequence outside of database

# File trailer
cpy.write(pack('!h', -1))

# Copy data to database
cpy.seek(0)
curs.copy_expert("COPY num_data FROM STDIN WITH BINARY", cpy)

# Update sequence on database
curs.execute("SELECT setval('num_data_id_seq', %s, false)", (id_seq,))
conn.commit()
```

---

## Update

I rewrote the above approach to writing the files for COPY. My data in Python is in NumPy arrays, so it makes sense to use these. Here is some example `data` with with 1M rows, 7 columns:

```py
import psycopg2
import numpy as np
from struct import pack
from io import BytesIO
from datetime import datetime

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mydb user=postgres")
curs = conn.cursor()

# NumPy record array
shape = (7, 2000, 500)
print('Generating data with %i rows, %i columns' % (shape[1]*shape[2], shape[0]))

dtype = ([('id', 'i4'), ('node', 'i4'), ('ts', 'i2')] +
         [('s' + str(x), 'f4') for x in range(shape[0])])
data = np.empty(shape[1]*shape[2], dtype)
data['id'] = np.arange(shape[1]*shape[2]) + 1
data['node'] = np.tile(np.arange(shape[1]) + 1, shape[2])
data['ts'] = np.repeat(np.arange(shape[2]) + 1, shape[1])
data['s0'] = np.random.rand(shape[1]*shape[2]) * 100
prv = 's0'
for nxt in data.dtype.names[4:]:
    data[nxt] = data[prv] + np.random.rand(shape[1]*shape[2]) * 10
    prv = nxt
```

On my database, I have two tables that look like:

```
CREATE TABLE num_data_binary
(
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  node integer NOT NULL,
  ts smallint NOT NULL,
  s0 real,
  s1 real,
  s2 real,
  s3 real,
  s4 real,
  s5 real,
  s6 real
) WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
```

and another similar table named `num_data_text`.

Here are some simple helper functions to prepare the data for COPY (both text and binary formats) by using the information in the NumPy record array:

```py
def prepare_text(dat):
    cpy = BytesIO()
    for row in dat:
        cpy.write('\t'.join([repr(x) for x in row]) + '\n')
    return(cpy)

def prepare_binary(dat):
    pgcopy_dtype = [('num_fields','>i2')]
    for field, dtype in dat.dtype.descr:
        pgcopy_dtype += [(field + '_length', '>i4'),
                         (field, dtype.replace('<', '>'))]
    pgcopy = np.empty(dat.shape, pgcopy_dtype)
    pgcopy['num_fields'] = len(dat.dtype)
    for i in range(len(dat.dtype)):
        field = dat.dtype.names[i]
        pgcopy[field + '_length'] = dat.dtype[i].alignment
        pgcopy[field] = dat[field]
    cpy = BytesIO()
    cpy.write(pack('!11sii', b'PGCOPY\n\377\r\n\0', 0, 0))
    cpy.write(pgcopy.tostring())  # all rows
    cpy.write(pack('!h', -1))  # file trailer
    return(cpy)
```

This how I'm using the helper functions to benchmark the two COPY format methods:

```py
def time_pgcopy(dat, table, binary):
    print('Processing copy object for ' + table)
    tstart = datetime.now()
    if binary:
        cpy = prepare_binary(dat)
    else:  # text
        cpy = prepare_text(dat)
    tendw = datetime.now()
    print('Copy object prepared in ' + str(tendw - tstart) + '; ' +
          str(cpy.tell()) + ' bytes; transfering to database')
    cpy.seek(0)
    if binary:
        curs.copy_expert('COPY ' + table + ' FROM STDIN WITH BINARY', cpy)
    else:  # text
        curs.copy_from(cpy, table)
    conn.commit()
    tend = datetime.now()
    print('Database copy time: ' + str(tend - tendw))
    print('        Total time: ' + str(tend - tstart))
    return

time_pgcopy(data, 'num_data_text', binary=False)
time_pgcopy(data, 'num_data_binary', binary=True)
```

Here is the output from the last two `time_pgcopy` commands:

```
Processing copy object for num_data_text
Copy object prepared in 0:01:15.288695; 84355016 bytes; transfering to database
Database copy time: 0:00:37.929166
        Total time: 0:01:53.217861
Processing copy object for num_data_binary
Copy object prepared in 0:00:01.296143; 80000021 bytes; transfering to database
Database copy time: 0:00:23.325952
        Total time: 0:00:24.622095
```

So both the NumPy → file and file → database steps are way faster with the binary approach. The obvious difference is how Python prepares the COPY file, which is really slow for text. Generally speaking, the binary format loads into the database in 2/3 of the time as the text format for this schema.

Lastly, I compared the values in both tables within the database to see if the numbers were different. About 1.46% of the rows have different values for column `s0`, and this fraction increases to 6.17% for `s6` (probably related on the random method that I used). The non-zero absolute differences between all 70M 32-bit float values range between 9.3132257e-010 and 7.6293945e-006. These small differences between the text and binary loading methods are due to the loss of precision from the float → text → float conversions required for the text format method.

Comment: Pretty cool. Did you write that yourself of get it from somewhere? And does it actually improve performance?

Comment: If it works, cool! Format aside, the solution however is to use psycopg's `copy_expert()`.

Comment: @Erwin, yes I programmed it using the excellent docs for [copy](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html), [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) and [dtype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html). Benchmarks are in, and are looking good.

Comment: @MikeToews I have noticed one thing in your code, that you have got value of sequence then updated its value back again, or solution could be to define sql as COPY table(column1,column2) FROM STDIN WITH BINARY.  Is there any special reason to do so. am using method by defining column names, this command works on terminal but do nothing in copy_expert.

Comment: I created a gem around this for ruby.  Most of the data types are supported.   https://github.com/pbrumm/pg_data_encoder

Comment: really nice piece of work, but where did you get postgresql data type identifiers?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/enomado/python-postgresql-load/) is my version. Based on Mike's version. Its very ad-hoc but there are two pros: - Expect generator and acts as a stream by overloading `readline` - Example how to write in `hstore` binary format.

Answer (score 0):

For those this still concerns.

I had to import `bytea` columns with `COPY`. I solved this for myself by importing the data to a temp table using `COPY FROM`, or psycopg2 `copy_from()`. Then, I did `UPDATE ... FROM` from the temp table to the actual data. In `UPDATE` statement I decode bytes presented as hexadecimal to actual `bytea` objects in SQL.

The only benefit of this approach, over PSQL binary import format, is that it is more human readable when data is transit and probably easier to code.

Note that [psycopg3](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html) has more advanced `COPY` capabilities, but I am currently using SQLALchemy 1.4 which is psycopg2.

Here is my Python example:

```py
        # Temp table is dropped at the end of the session
        # https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-temporary-table/
        # This must match data_as_dicts structure.
        # We will pass binary data as hex strings in an unprefixed format:
        # 01020304
        sql = f"""
        CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {temp_table_name}
        (
          id int,
          sync_event_id int,
          sync_reserve0 varchar(128), 
          sync_reserve1 varchar(128)
        );    
        """
        conn.execute(sql)

        # Clean any pending data in the temp table
        # between update chunks.
        # TODO: Not sure why this does not clear itself at conn.close()
        # as I would expect based on the documentation.
        sql = f"TRUNCATE {temp_table_name}"
        conn.execute(sql)

        # Load data from CSV to the temp table
        # https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html
        cursor = conn.connection.cursor()
        out.seek(0)
        cursor.copy_from(out, temp_table_name, sep=delim, columns=columns)

        # Fill real table from the temp table
        # This copies values from the temp table using
        # UPDATE...FROM and matching by the row id.
        # We will also reconstruct binary from the hex strings.
        sql = f"""
        UPDATE {real_table_name}  
        SET 
            sync_event_id=b.sync_event_id,
            sync_reserve0=decode(b.sync_reserve0, 'hex'),
            sync_reserve1=decode(b.sync_reserve1, 'hex')        
        FROM {temp_table_name} AS b 
        WHERE {real_table_name}.id=b.id;
        """
        res = conn.execute(sql)
        logger.debug("Updated %d rows", res.rowcount)
```