# Postgresql multi-row insert using command parameters

Tags: c#, postgresql

I need to insert large amounts of data into postgresql using multi-row inserts.

I am currently doing this by constructing the sql query using a stringbuilder and appending the values but I was wondering if there is a way to use commands and command parameters instead?

Comment: Use `COPY`. See the npgsql manual.

Comment: Thanks. I have already checked that and I was having problems because of the data I need to import

Comment: Consider `COPY`ing to a `TEMPORARY` or `UNLOGGED` table then doing an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to insert a massaged version of the data into the real target table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is good [copy guide](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html) for inserting big amount of data.
Here is [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206600/how-to-speed-up-insertion-performance-in-postgresql) for similar question