# Multiple connections to PostgreSQL with huge number of INSERTs

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-performance

This question is involved by this one: [How to speed up insertion performance in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206600/how-to-speed-up-insertion-performance-in-postgresql)

So, I have java application which is doing a lot of (aprox. billion) INSERTs into `PostgreSQL` database. It opens several JDBC connections to the same DB for doing these inserts in parallel. As I read in mentioned question-answer:

> INSERT or COPY in parallel from several connections. How many depends
>   on your hardware's disk subsystem; as a rule of thumb, you want one
>   connection per physical hard drive if using direct attached storage.

But in my case I have only **one disk storage** for my DB.

So, my question is: does it really have sence to open several connections in this case? Could it reduce perfomance instead of desired increasing due to I/O operations competitions?

For clarifying, here is the picture with actual `postgresql` processes load:

[image]

Comment: It depends on the disk, CPU, how much CPU work is involved in processing the data load, etc. *Test it and see*. In general I'd be surprised if you benefited from more than two concurrent `COPY` sessions unless you have a high performance SSD. If you insist on using `INSERT`s instead, then there are all sorts of overheads, so more may be helpful. Again, *test and see*. Or better, switch to `COPY`.

Comment: @CraigRinger I can not `COPY` because I'm reading `XML` files and pushing almost its content into `bytea` column. Preparing these files in new format doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Yeah, you can, you just need to supply the input in the right format. If you aren't sure, try `COPY FROM` to dump a table you've loaded a little data into; also take a look at the documentation for details on the format. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html . And remember you can use `COPY` via PgJDBC using the `CopyManager` API.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned `INSERT` in Java application, I'd assume (utilizing plain JDBC) `COPY` is not what you're looking for. Without using API like [JPA](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr338/) or framework such as [Spring-data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/), may I introduce [`addBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29) and [`executeBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29) in case you haven't heard of these:

```
/*
 the whole nine yards
 */
Connection c = ...;
PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table1(columnInt2,columnVarchar)VALUES(?,?)");
```

Then read data in a loop:

```
ps.setShort(1, someShortValue);
ps.setString(2, someStringValue);
ps.addBatch();  // one row at a time from human's perspective
```

When data of all rows are prepared:

```
ps.executeBatch();
```

May I also recommend:

- [Connection pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) which saves you a lot of resources; check out [Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/), [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) and [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/).
- When doing multiple [CUD (create, update, delete)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations, one should think about transaction (so you can rollback in case any row goes wrong).

Comment: It's a very broad answer, which doesn't cover exactly my case and isn't related to `PostgreSQL`'s features.