# Scheduling a postgreSQL query operating on greenplum DB

Tags: postgresql, scheduling, greenplum

I have a table that has to be populated every hour from the data being pulled out of Greenplum.This table is being stored on the Greenplum server.

So,what I want to know is that what method(python script, windows scheduler or anything) will be suitable for my data(which I guess can be as huge as 60GB or more) should be used for scheduling the query(written in postgreSQL) to be run every hour.

Can someone attach a sample code for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to do a parallel `COPY` of ranges of the data out of Greenplum and into PostgreSQL. Make sure PostgreSQL is set up for fast data loading. If possible, use an `UNLOGGED` table; otherwise use `wal_level = 'minimal'` at least.

How many parallel workers depends on the PostgreSQL server's I/O subsystem more than anything. Test and see.

I would recommend using Python with psycopg2 and the `copy_expert` cursor function. See [the docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from). Use multiprocessing with a pipe to share a file-like object between a reader and writer worker, with the reader connected to greenplum and the writer to PostgreSQL.

So effectively each worker does something a bit like the following shell pseudo-code:

```
psql -h greenplum-box \
     -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 10000) TO stdin" \
  | \
psql -h postgres-box \
     -c "COPY myttable FROM stdin";
```

(but you connect the two up using pyscopg2, `copy_export`, multiprocessing, and a pipe).

Do all the usual fast loading work like creating indexes afterwards. See [how to speed up insertion performance in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12206600/398670).

If you have the disk space, create a table like `dataload_temp`, populate it, then in one transaction drop the old one and rename the new one to the old one's name. That way there's minimal disruption.

Alternately, take a look at `pg_bulkload` for off-line (but non-streaming) bulk data loading.

Comment: @craig..I am learning GP,postgreSQL and Python all at once and I have been working on it for past 20 hours only. The links are helpful but I have one confusion

Comment: @craig..I am learning GP,postgreSQL and Python all at once and I have been working on it for past 20 hours only. The links are helpful but I have one confusion i.e.do I need to use the copy_to and copy_from if I have queries of the following kind cur.execute(create table abc.....);cur.execute(insert into table abc values...(select....));

Comment: @user3336746 You use `COPY ... FROM STDOUT` *instead of* `INSERT INTO ...`. It's a more efficient way to load data. See the PostgreSQL user manual. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html . And you can use `COPY ... TO STDOUT` to extract data from Greenplum. Hence my recommendation to connect the two together using a pipe to stream data between the DBs.

Comment: Added some pseudo code that might help you understand. You will need to do some study to learn how to do this quickly and in parallel.

Comment: I don't need a file.! What I need is just a subset of the data on greenplum and this subset is to be stored on greenplum only.So, why do I need a file?

Comment: @user3336746 I think you must've misunderstood. Read again. There's a pipe between two `COPY`s. Do you know what a pipe is in unix?