# PostgreSQL shared_buffers on Windows

Tags: performance, postgresql

I'm runnung 64-bit PostgreSQL 9.1 on Windows Server. I'm trying to improve its performanace especially for handling heavy writing. I used to increase shared_buffer to %25 of RAM, and scine I got 32GB RAM I decided to set **shared_buffers** to **8GB**. While I'm searching for more info I came across this post: http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2012/03/tuning-sharedbuffers-and-walbuffers.html

It says: `but not more than about 8GB on Linux or 512MB on Windows, and sometimes less.`

Now I'm confused. What's the point of increasing RAM if it won't help improving PostgreSQL performance?!

The other values will be as follows:

```
work_mem: 160MB
maintenance_work_mem = 1920MB
checkpoint_segments = 100
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
checkpoint_timeout = 1h
wal_buffers = 64MB
effective_cache_size = 22GB
```

Comment: The general assumption is, that the management overhead of a large shared buffers can make things slower. You may also want to read this: http://www.keithf4.com/a-large-database-does-not-mean-large-shared_buffers/ and this http://evol-monkey.blogspot.de/2013/08/setting-sharedbuffers-hard-way.html and this http://www.cybertec.at/postgresql-9-3-shared-buffers-performance-1/ You also might wan to upgrade to a more up-to-date version, as there were some improvements in the memory management in 9.3

Comment: `shared_buffers` is also just not as helpful for write loads. You want to focus more on checkpoint spreading, on effective batching in the application, on turning off `synchronous_commit` where safe (preferably at the app level per-transaction), etc. There's no magic "go faster" config option and appropriate configuration depends on the workload. For inserting and bulk loading see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206600/how-to-speed-up-insertion-performance-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

For a write-heavy Windows server, the most important setting is to adjust checkpoint_segments.  Your value is fairly high already, but you may want to experiment with values up to 256.

From the postgresql performance tuning guide (found [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server)):

> PostgreSQL writes new transactions to the database in files called WAL segments that are 16MB in size. Every time checkpoint_segments worth of these files have been written, by default 3, a checkpoint occurs. Checkpoints can be resource intensive, and on a modern system doing one every 48MB will be a serious performance bottleneck. Setting checkpoint_segments to a much larger value improves that. Unless you're running on a very small configuration, you'll almost certainly be better setting this to at least 10, which also allows usefully increasing the completion target.
>
> For more write-heavy systems, values from 32 (checkpoint every 512MB) to 256 (every 4GB) are popular nowadays. Very large settings use a lot more disk and will cause your database to take longer to recover, so make sure you're comfortable with both those things before large increases. Normally the large settings (>64/1GB) are only used for bulk loading. Note that whatever you choose for the segments, you'll still get a checkpoint at least every 5 minutes unless you also increase checkpoint_timeout (which isn't necessary on most systems).