# How to avoid data loss in python postgresql bulk insertion

Tags: python, postgresql, bulkinsert

I want to insert my data into PostgreSQL 1000 by 1000 records ( Bulk Insertion ) to make it quick and low load on the DBMS, So my code for now is :

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bar(first_name,last_name) VALUES ('David', 'Bar')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bar(first_name,last_name) VALUES ('David2', 'Bar2')")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bar(first_name,last_name) VALUES ('David3', 'Bar3')")
.... etc
connection.commit()
```

And as you can see i committed the changes at the end and that's saving a lot of time for me instated of committing the changes after every insert query.
The problem is if any query crashed for any reason ( invalid data ), all the quires will fail to execute and i will lose the data.
Is there anyway to save the time of the insertion and avoid the data loss at the same time??

Comment: Are using any framework or ORM?

Comment: No i'm using psycopg2.

Comment: See [this answer][1] to your question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206600/how-to-speed-up-insertion-performance-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements of course, depending on your transaction needs I would recommend one of the following options:

### 1. Using [`SAVEPOINT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-savepoint.html)'s (subtransactions):

```
BEGIN;
    SAVEPOINT savepoint;
    INSERT ...;
    RELEASE savepoint;
    SAVEPOINT savepoint;
    INSERT ...;
    /* If you're getting an error */
    ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT savepoint;
COMMIT;
```

### 2. Using [`AUTOCOMMIT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/ecpg-sql-set-autocommit.html)

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT TO ON;
INSERT ...
INSERT ...
INSERT ...
```