# Hibernate multi row insert postgresql

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, insert, multirow

Now I have working batch inserts with hibernate ("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 50)
but as far as i know **hibernate generates single** inserts in batches. 
I know that I can **tell** my db driver to **create multi-row insert** for every batch of inserts to speed up performance using rewriteBatchedStatements:
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?rewriteBatchedStatements=true

But in db logs there are still single inserts.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: How do you generate primary keys?

Answer (score 4):

This actually has nothing to do with Hibernate. The inserts are handled by the JDBC driver.

`rewriteBatchedStatements` is a MySQL specific parameter so it won't work with a PostgreSQL database. If you really need to do bulk inserts with PostgreSQL, take a look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12207237/1743880) which explains how to do it.