# Appropriate column type for storing 16K binary blocks in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, throughput

My application needs to store millions of binary blocks in a Postgres database (a few thousands of those might arrive per second). Most of the blocks are 16K in size though some might be smaller. I understand that I can use text, bytea or blob columns or I can store the binary data in files outside the database and put their paths in the table.

Considering that **high write-throughput** is my most important goal, which option is the most appropriate for my situation?

Comment: If those blocks are compressable (i.e. have repeated values), then `bytea` might be a good option because it compresses the data. But I agree with Tom: you will have to test the performance for yourself, this is impossible to answer in a "general" way. I personally would first test the `bytea` solution and see if it can support the performance requirements

Comment: Benchmarking different approaching is of course on my agenda. I was just wondering weather there well-known facts that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bytea` is the sensible option here - almost the only option.

There is *no* advantage to using `text`, `varchar` etc. Don't store encoded binary in them. That's an option you should immediately disregard.

There is no `blob` type in PostgreSQL. I think you might mean `lob`, which is a wrapper for `oid` used for looking up "large objects" in the `pg_largeobject` table. This is useful when you need virtual "files" in the database where you can seek, overwrite, append, etc, but it's not at all suited to your use case.

You *could* store paths or filenames then look them up externally, but you're going to have a *lot* of very small files. You're also going to need a sidechannel for clients to read and write them, since you can't use the PostgreSQL protocol directly. You'll need to handle backup/restore and replication for them separately. They won't get deleted if a transaction rolls back or if the corresponding database tuple gets deleted so you'll need a cleanup system to remove no-longer-needed files. It'll get messy. This is worth doing when the files are big, long-lived, and mostly static, but it doesn't sound like that's the case for you.

Store the binary in `bytea` columns directly, and preferably use the binary protocol support in PgJDBC or `libpq` to exchange the bytea values between client and server without needing encoding. Have minimal indexes on the table you write to. (Under some circumstances you can even go without defining a primary key, but that's kind of an expert level option). If you don't mind losing the data in the table on unplanned restart, use an unlogged table. Otherwise batch writes and use asynchronous commits and/or a commit delay.

See also [How to speed up insertion performance in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12206600/398670)

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you. About using the binary protocol support in libpq, does it suffice to use `PQexecParams` and ask for the binary format in `paramFormats`?

Comment: @Elektito Yep, that's fine for reading. For writing you have to specify a parameter formats array for your query parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try all your options, benchmark them, and figure out which one works best for you.