# Way to import 41mln records by file with inserts

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I have really big sql file with only imports commands (29GB with over 41000000 exported records).

When I want to import it into existing table, I use PSQL Console with simply command `\i path/with/file.sql` and it takes about 5 hours.
Is this the best way to do it on desktop database? I read about bulk, but not sure about possibility to use it in my case.

Comment: As per an other question, there is a Postgresql guide on bulk importing here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html  are you saying that you have no control over the creation of the bulk file?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206600/how-to-speed-up-insertion-performance-in-postgresql