# Most efficient way to import data to Prisma / PostgreSQL service?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have a Prisma (1.14.2) service running that is attached to a PostgreSQL database. I need to insert a lot of nodes with a one-to-many relation to the PostgreSQL database via the Prisma connector. Right now I am doing this in the following way. The `strokes` and `samples` arrays hold a lot of nodes:

```
for (let strokeIndex = 0; strokeIndex < painting.strokes.length; strokeIndex++) {
    const stroke = painting.strokes[strokeIndex];
    const samples = stroke.samples;
    const createdStroke = await PrismaServer.mutation.createStroke({
        data: {
            myId: stroke.id,
            myCreatedAt: new Date(stroke.createdAt),
            brushType: stroke.brushType,
            color: stroke.color,
            randomSeed: stroke.randomSeed,
            painting: {connect: {myId: jsonPainting.id}},
            samples: { create: samples }
        }
    });
}
```

In the case of 128 strokes and 128 samples for each stroke (i.e. 16348 samples in total) **this takes about 38 seconds**.

I am wondering if there is a way to speed up the process? Especially since the number of strokes and samples can get much higher. I could use `prisma import ...`, which showed a 6x speedup. But I want to avoid the required conversion to the [Normalized Data Format (NDF)](https://prisma-docs.netlify.com/docs/reference/data-import-and-export/normalized-data-format-teroo5uxih).

I read about speeding up the INSERTs in PostgreSQL [in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206600/how-to-speed-up-insertion-performance-in-postgresql), but I am not sure if and how I can apply that to the Prisma connector.

Comment: I couldn't post this before you deleted your latest question so just letting you know here: FWIW, if you have a `std::string` or `std::string_view` you can just use `string_variable.front() == string_variable.back()` not pay all the cost needed for a regex

Answer (score 0):

Round trips (querying your API, that query your database, and returns the values) takes a lot of time. 
Actually, it certainly takes more time than the actual SQL query.

To solve your problem, you should probably  **batch**  your queries. There are many ways to do it, you can use a GraphQL query batching package, or simply do it like this :

```
mutation {
  q1: createStroke(color: "red") {
    id
  }
  q2: createStroke(color: "blue") {
    id
  }
}
```

Remember that Prisma [will time out queries taking longer than 45s](https://www.prisma.io/forum/t/what-is-the-limit-size-of-batched-queries/450), therefore you may want to limit your batches size.

Given n the number of queries per batch, it will divide the number of round trips by n.

Answer (score 0):

Since Prisma version 2.20.0, you should be able to use `.createMany({})` now.
Probably this answer won't be helpful since you asked 3years ago...

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#create-multiple-records