# SQL Alchemy Bulk update table values from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to bulk update a table using a dataframe using the row id. I tried using the pandas but it didnt work

```
df.to_sql("collections.tbl_products", engin=local_db_engine, if_exists="replace", index=False, index_label='id', chunksize=10000)
```

SQL Table (name='tbl_products' schema = 'collections'):

| id | name | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apples | 123 |
| 2 | bananas | 456 |

My dataframe:

| id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 789 |
| 2 | 654 |

I know I could do a row by row update using sql alchemy but how would I do a bulk update using my df?

Note - I'm  a complete new beginner at this

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58826647/2144390