# PostgreSQL Insert Performance

Tags: postgresql

**Hardware/Software:**

- Mac M1
- MySQL 8.1, JDBC Driver 8.0.33
- PostgreSQL 16, JDBC Driver 42.6.0
- Hikari connection pool (auto commit is **off**)

**My setup:**

I'm creating a database of cricket scores and I have ~170,000 scorecards on disk in JSON format. Up until this week I've been using MySQL for the database and everything was OK but I seem to have hit an issue in the database where it's returning invalid data (that's not this question). To investigate this further and make sure it's not my data/code that's causing the issue I decided to duplicate what I have into PostgreSQL, I've also heard great things about the perf of PostgreSQL so this would be a win/win.

To load the data into the database I have a Java application (Kotlin actually, but same difference) that uses JDBC. I need to occasionally blow away my DB and reload it from scratch because reasons. So this rebuild happens relatively frequently (about once every 6 weeks or so).

For each card on the filesystem, I load it into memory and then create a set of SQL insert statements to insert the card into the tables in the DB, there are 34 tables, and each card generates somewhere in the region of 100 to 200 insert statements (if you don't know cricket, think baseball, lots of batter/bowler/fielder stats to be added for each card). There are essentially two sorts of card, long and short, the long card generates about twice the data of the short card, so maybe 100 to 200 inserts for the short cards and 150 to 400 inserts for the long cards.

I have exactly the same database structure (modulo simple changes for auto generated primary key syntax for the two DBs) and exactly the same code, the only difference being the JDBC driver I use.

**The issue:**

On MySQL the update runs in a reasonable time, a in the order of 3 to 4 hours. For the short card the code takes about 150ms to run all the inserts and add the card to the database.

On PostgerSQL the same code takes about 600ms to run, i.e. 4 times more slowly.

For the longer cards PostgreSQL initially takes ~600ms to insert the card but by the time I killed the app (after running for about 12 hours) this time has stretched to ~1.6 seconds!

**What I've Tried:**

For PostgreSQL (but not MySQL) I've removed indices and foreign keys from the tables to try and speed things up although it doesn't seem to have made any difference.

I'm batching inserts where I can.

I'm committing one 'card' at a time

I've seen numerous questions on this including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206600/how-to-speed-up-insertion-performance-in-postgresql) and tried to follow this advice there.

As I said above I've removed foreign keys and indexes and I think I've disabled triggers (`ALTER ROLE myrole SET session_replication_role = 'replica';`).

My current thought is to load the data into MySQL and then bulk COPY across to PostgreSQL but that seems nuts :)

I'd love be able to get a handle on this and understand why an insert is so much slower on PostgreSQL, I feel like I'm missing something in my setup.

I am a complete PostgreSQL newbie so I have little idea on how to go about analysing this so any help would be greatfully received (I'm also on holiday and travelling at the moment so I'm snatching time where I can to look at this!)

**Update 1**

To answer some of the questions.

Transactions: I'm not specifically using setting any transaction level, I'm using whatever the JDBC driver/PostgreSQL default is. Apart from that I turn off auto-commit and then commit for each card.

JSON Object: I really don't want to copy one of those here, although I'm happy to put one on Dropbox if you think it will help.

"120,000 scorecards in 3 to 4 hours", that's for MySQL, PostgreSQL takes way longer than this, I've never got close to the end of the run and that's after 12 to 14 hours. Also it's 170,000 cards (my apologies, I've edited the original question)

If I run a timer for a subset of cards I get this: 13821 cards added in 479105ms that means so 29 cards a second, this is for the smaller cards, the larger cards would be slower. If I turn off all logging then this rises to about 30 cards a second.

Looking at one card at random this inserts about 250 rows into the tables (a longer card would be roughly double this) so about 7500 rows a second, which I think is much closer (or better than) the comments here think I should get. To me this means that the code/MySQL combination is working well

"Why not use JDBC COPY directly? " a) because the data is not in that format and b) I'm trying (at least initially) to keep the code I use for MySQL the same as the code I use for PostgreSQL. To use copy would be a major rewrite to get the data into the correct format (unless there's a way i can get the JDBC driver to do it for me?)

"Any randomly generated columns like OIDs?" No, just auto generated primary keys.

"Just INSERTs or are there UPDATEs too?" Just inserts

"Large data types like long TEXT columns or arrays of more than a few kilobytes"?  Yes, there are many text columns

"Have you tried unlogged tables?" No, I did read about that somewhere and it was on my list of things to try, but I'd really, really like to keep the same codebase for any database I might want to use.

"What is the MySQL table type used, InnoDB or MyISAM?" InnoDB

"Maybe buffers are too small", Maybe - how do I check/change this?
"or the machine is swapping?"  Maybe, but it's a 32GB machine so I thought this would be unlikely

"Note if you're only getting 1000 INSERTs/s on MySQL it's already extremely slow so something's wrong on the MySQL side too. " I think I underestimated this in my original post, I'm getting something like 7500 INSERTs/s on MySQL

"Is it also doing SELECTs?" Yes, I do a select to see if the card exists and then run the inserts if not, this is **one** select per card, not one select per insert

"Have you profiled the code?" No - but I don't think it's a code issue, it;s the same code for MySQL and PostgreSQL.

"How many parallel threads?" One

**Update 2**
I've been running the code just to get performance timings to see if I can shine more light on this. A 'default' MySQL run using a connection pool gives me this

```
100 cards added in 3522ms       = 28.39 cards/sec
1000 cards added in 29732ms     = 33.63 cards/sec
2000 cards added in 58166ms     = 34.38 cards/sec
3000 cards added in 87571ms     = 34.25 cards/sec
10000 cards added in 304676ms   = 32.82 cards/sec
13821 cards added in 450690ms   = 29.47 cards/sec
```

So it runs consistently at about 30 cards (7500 rows) a second.

A default PostgreSQL run looks like this:

```
100 cards added in 2616ms       = 38.22 cards/sec
1000 cards added in 47710ms     = 20.95
2000 cards added in 134087ms    = 14.92
3000 cards added in 233580ms    = 12.84
10000 cards added in 1567393ms  = 6.38
13821 cards added in 2763865ms  = 5.00
```

It starts off better that MySQL (which is what I hoped) but it falls away rapidly.

I've then tried several things.

1. I've tried removing the connection pool and then opening and closing the JDBC connection once for every card (to try and free any resources)
2. I've tried removing the connection pool and using one JDBC connection for the single run

In both these cases the results are about the same as above (38 cards/sec over the first hundred cards dropping to 5 cards/second by the time 13,000 cards are processed)

So I'm now wondering if it's something in my app that's causing the go-slow. To test this I start the app, let it add about 4000 cards, kill my app, then stop and restart the PostgreSQL serice and start my app again and the results are exactly the same.

I've also tried killing the run after about 4000 cards then rebooting the machine, and again the same result.

(Everything above is done against a clean database, delete all the tables and then re-create them, no foreign keys, no indexes)

The table definitions are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/k8lnsfavvofhgy0vzz3ra/1__nofk__initial_tables.sql?rlkey=5btmut9pnbhkvrsnvhyohld0q&dl=0)

Comment: Hard to help you without any information about the configuration, DDL and SQL statements. Do you use transactions and if so, what transaction level? And what about concurrency? How many concurrent processes are running?

Comment: And could you share the content of one of these JSON objects?

Comment: 120,000 scorecards in 3 to 4 hours is imho pretty slow, that's about 10 cards per second. On your Mac I would expect something in the range of 1000 to 3000 per second. Did you run pgbench on your Mac? If so, what are the results for a medium to large database?

Comment: Why not use JDBC [COPY](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/server-prepare/#copymanager) directly?

Comment: This needs more info about table structure. Any randomly generated columns like OIDs? Just INSERTs or are there UPDATEs too? Large data types like long TEXT columns or arrays of more than a few kilobytes? Have you tried unlogged tables? What is the MySQL table type used, InnoDB or MyISAM? Maybe buffers are too small, or the machine is swapping? Note if you're only getting 1000 INSERTs/s on MySQL it's already extremely slow so something's wrong on the MySQL side too. Is it also doing SELECTs? Have you profiled the code? How many parallel threads?

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far. I've updated the original question to show what I've tried, to show what the performance looks like and to try and answer some of the questions people asked