# Manually convert PostgreSQL binary format of timestamp to integer

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, binary-data

I've read that PostgreSQL internally stores timestamps as an 8-byte/64-bit integer.

To check this I've created a table, inserted some timestamps and queried the `heap_page_items`.
The output e.g. for timestamp `2019-01-08 09:00:00`  was `00  e4  c2  56  ed  21  02  00`.

Given this hex sequence, how do I manually compute the number of microseconds since PostgreSQL epoch (2000-01-01)? Using a timestamp converter I got value `600253200000` as result. How do I have to "unpack" the bytes to receive this value?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What's wrong with `extract(epoch from ...)`?

Comment: I need to identify a range of raw pages of a large index (millions of entries) containing timestamps to apply some optimizations, like prewarming the buffer_cache etc. Besides that I'm interested in how this works, as I plan to write some code that produces binary files using this format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your analysis is almost perfect, and you must be on a little-endian machine.

You don't have to unpack the value, because on your 64-bit architecture 8-byte integers can fit into a PostgreSQL `Datum`.

```
SELECT extract(epoch FROM TIMESTAMP '2019-01-08 09:00:00')
     - extract(epoch FROM TIMESTAMP '2000-01-01 00:00:00');

 ?column?  
-----------
 600253200
(1 row)
```

600253200 seconds are 600253200000000 microseconds.

The integer you see in the table is 0x000221ed56c2e400, which corresponds to decimal 600253200000000:

```bash
bash> printf "%ld\n" 0x000221ed56c2e400
600253200000000
```

Comment: Doh! That was way too simple :) Thanks!