# PostgreSQL: Need to chose between COPY'ing from a file or from stdin

Tags: database, postgresql, csv, query-optimization

I'm inserting millions of records, coming from C++ structures. With regular inserts, I'm getting a terrible performance, with the database taking up 98% of program time, even after config optimization. I'm reading that I should use COPY to import it from a CSV-file.

Now I'm not so sure if writing to a CSV-file first and then rewriting it to the DB will be much of an improvement, since the writing will double. I've looked at piping the STDIN, but at first glance it seems like there's also much overhead, and it's limited

If I've got a string in CSV-format, what would be the quickest way to write that data to my DB?

Thank you in advance,

CX

Comment: Are these millions of records the same every time?  Is your database not persistent?

Comment: The same columns, different data. The database is persistent, afaik.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the table? Triggers? Constraints? Are you batching the inserts inside transactions?

Comment: No indexes besides PK, no triggers, tons of FK's. No batching.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758945/whats-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-bulk-insert-into-postgres

Comment: Yeah I passed by there, I'm wondering how.

Comment: What sort of overhead do you expect from piping from stdin?  And how it is limited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you need to do it once on an offline database. If you need to do it on an online database there's not much you can do besides using a `your-program-generating-a-copy-command | psql` or [`PQputCopyData`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-copy.html) from your program.

1. Disable all other access to database, terminate all client connections.

   Backup a database without your bulk data, as this procedure is dangerous (a crash, reboot or power failure during this will make your database corrupted beyond repair).

   Shutdown database.

   Move `pg_xlog` directory from data directory to a `tmpfs` (RAM-disk), symlink it.

   Run `postgres -F -c full_page_writes=off -c checkpoint_segments=128 …`. It will need about 2GB of free RAM more than usually — be prepared.

   Drop primary key contraint from your table.

   Drop foreign key constraints from your table.

   Load data using COPY from stdin and a pipe or `PQputCopyData`.

   Run `analyze`.

   Recreate primary key constraint.

   Recreate foreign key constraints (a file generated by `pg_dump` before dropping them will have suitable commands near the end).

   Shutdown database.

   Delete `pg_xlog` symlink and move `pg_xlog` directory back to data directory.

   Run `sync` command on server.

   Start database normally.

This is based on [Populating a Database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html) guide from documentation.