# How can I speed up the importing process to a postgres database?

Tags: java, postgresql-8.4

I am importing some data from a 10Gb file to a postgres database tables using java (jdbc). Import process taking more 12 hours to complete, so need to improve the importing process. I tried copy command for inserting. Some select commands are also running with the inserting tables. Can anyone suggests the way to improve the speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard SQL `INSERT` statement typically has a too big overhead when millions of rows are needed. 10 GiB of data isn't really that much, but certainly too much for `INSERT` (you either have a huge transaction or commit/rollback every INSERT).

There is a nice [*14.4. Populating a Database*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html) chapter in official documentation. *14.4.2. Use `COPY`* is especially interesting for you:

> Use `COPY` to load all the rows in one command, instead of using a series of INSERT commands. The `COPY` command is optimized for loading large numbers of rows; it is less flexible than `INSERT`, but incurs significantly less overhead for large data loads. Since `COPY` is a single command, there is no need to disable autocommit if you use this method to populate a table.

## See also:

- [Whats the fastest way to do a bulk insert into Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758945)

Comment: I am dropping indexes before going to use copy command,is that going to affect the select command??

Comment: @user1782877: according to *14.4.3. Remove Indexes* it will make import faster but `select` statement slower (at least for the time when you do an import).