# Insert values into table at the end of the query

Tags: postgresql

In my query im using for loop. Each and every time when for loop is executed, at the end some values has to be inserted into table. This is time consuming because for loop has many records. Due to this each and every time when for loop is executed, insertion is happening.

Is there any other way to perform insertion at the end after the for loop is executed?

```
For i in 1..10000 loop
.... --coding
 insert into datas.tb values(j,predictednode);  -- j and predictednode are variables which will change for every loop

End loop;
```

Instead of inserting each and every time i want the insertion should happen at the end.

Comment: Please show us a representative example of your code.

Comment: `@user2659199` google it and try it yourself, if any problem then ask question with your code...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest 2 solutions.

1. Bulk Insert -  http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTik-czdrdLmbcG966HoF72F2b561R9Uuh54Os94f@mail.gmail.com

   Stackoverflow : [Whats the fastest way to do a bulk insert into Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758945/whats-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-bulk-insert-into-postgres)
2. Pass XML as argument type to PostgreSQL - http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1310832875860-4594251.post@n5.nabble.com

   XML Type - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-xml.html