# In ruby on rails application how can i upload 3 GB csv file to the pg database on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv, upload, postgresql-copy

I want to upload 3 GB csv file to the pg database on server.

I need to finish this operation in 4 to 5 hours.

Please show me the way to upload data to server from csv file.

Comment: you need http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import

Comment: Worth mentioning that you can use `scp` to get the file onto your server in the first place.  Don't use Git.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/758945/398670, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12206600/398670

Answer (score 0):

If you can take the DB offline, copy the file to the server with (e.g.) `scp`, then use [`pg_bulkload`](https://github.com/ossc-db/pg_bulkload).

Otherwise split it into chunks and use psql's `\copy` to load the chunks in parallel, after dropping indexes etc.

See also:

- [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/populate.html)
- [Whats the fastest way to do a bulk insert into Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/758945/398670)
- [How to speed up insertion performance in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12206600/398670)