# Processing large data (xls, csv, google sheets) and storing it in the database

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, multiprocessing, celery

There is the following business logic.

User uploads a file (*xls, csv, google sheet*). Files can be about **80K lines**.

From the data in each row, records are created in the database (`PostgreSQL`). Each record is indexed in `ElasticSearch`.

It takes quite a long time. Therefore, I make data processing, writing to the database in `celery`.

How else can speed up data processing, creating records in the database? `Multiprocesses`? `Threads`? `Celery chunks`?

Comment: There are a lot of best practices for performance tuning for this use case, 
For instance - You can try inserting to postgres in batches of 1k-5k, And do the same for the elasticsearch,
Also - you can consider indexing in elasticsearch in a separated thread so it won't be synchronous process

Comment: @planben I thought about this way. Could you give an example?

Comment: If anything, I am using Flask and SqlAlchemy

Comment: when looking for an example I encountered the following post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758945/whats-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-bulk-insert-into-postgres
which lead me to the following postgres copy command which can take a csv file and load it to a table - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html

Comment: @planben It's not all that simple. On the data that I receive from files, I need to perform certain operations in a loop (~80K iterations!!!) and only then write them to the database. Therefore, it will not be so easy to insert data from the table into the database.

Comment: I still think that copy will do the job if you'll write the post-manipulated rows into a file and then load it using COPY to postgres,
But there are alternatives, you can also use bulk insert - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/dml-insert.html - one insert command to insert multiple rows, you can try to fine tune that number to see which one works the best for you, since you file is 80k rows - I would start with 4k